# Java's Random.nextInt() produces numbers between what and what?

Tags: java, random, int

The **Oracle java doc** says that

> All **2<sup>32</sup>** possible int values are produced with (approximately) equal probability.

Does this mean that the values generated range from **-(2<sup>32</sup>)** to **2<sup>32</sup>**, or would that mean **-(2<sup>16</sup>)** to **2<sup>16</sup>**?

Comment: -(2^32) to 2^32 is 2^33+1 values. -(2^16) to 2^16 is 2^17+1 values.  This is not Java, just plain maths. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means from −2<sup>31</sup> (`java.lang.Integer.MIN_VALUE`) to 2<sup>31</sup>−1 (`java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE`). See [the Javadoc for `java.lang.Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), or [§4.2.1 "Integral Types and Values" of *The Java Language Specification*, Java SE 7 Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1).

Comment: do you mean -2^-31 or -2^31?

Comment: @vishal_aim: Whoops, ha, thanks, fixed. That would be an interesting definition of "int"! :-P

Answer (score 0):

As the docs says, nextInt() returns an int and in java int is a 32-bit integer. So it would be in that [range](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1).